# gui application to custom regional settings

Tags: 16.04, gui, system-settings, locale

I am installing Ubuntu 16.04 and using gnome-shell (wich is very awesome by the way), i try to make first weekday and first workday to Sunday, tried everything in a lot of forums:

`sudo gedit /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US`
`sudo locale-gen`
`restart`

also editing  `/etc/locale.gen`

nothing works for me,

Comment: Can you show us the edits you made?

Comment: `week    7;19971130;4`    
`first_weekday 1`    
`first_workday 1`    
`END LC_TIME`

Comment: Can it be that the application, whose behavior you try to change, doesn't care about the locale? What's the output of the commands `locale first_weekday` and `locale first_workday`?

Comment: you are right, both commands returns the value "1". And about the application it's not actually an application it's the gnome-shell calendar.  I tried to check gnome-calendar, the first_weekday is Sunday (witch marked as the only day in the weekend), and the first workday is Monday (visible in the Year view), but in gnome-shell calendar i have both Sunday and Saturday as weekend days.

Comment: in the "language support" doesen't matter what i choose, it depends only to the "language" choosen: 
for example i am choosing "english (united kingdom) as language for my menues and windows, doesen't matter what i choose for "regional formats" it is always set to "en_GB", i tried to change it in /etc/default/locale, try `$ locale-gen ar_DZ.UTF-8` for example there is no error but whatever i do when i execute `$ locale` it is all set with "en_GB.UTF-8", the only thing that works is to put the whole language to "ar_DZ.UTF-8", in that case the command `$ locale` gives me "ar_DZ.UTF-8".

Comment: If you choose Arabic (Algeria) as the Regional Formats setting in Language Support, you need to re-login for it to be effective. (How is this related to your question above?)

Comment: every time i made a change i reboot the whole system to be sure, i've tried everyting. Now about my question: in gnome-shell calendar applet I wanted to change two things:  1- firstweekday : wich is "Sunday" here in Algeria 2- firstworkday : wich is also "Sunday", but i like to use "English" as my language, if i change the whole thing (to ar_DZ), my whole interface will be in Arabic (witch I am not used to work with) and first_weekday and first_workday will be :"Sunday",

Comment: but when i revert the "language for menus and windows" to English the system ignores the "Regional Formats" what ever i choose and revert it to English, so the "Regional Formats" option is not working, and all workaround i did in the terminal are not working either, and when "I thought may be its a system bug", when i try to edit en_GB file the only value that effective is first_weekday, but the first_workday is stuck to "Sunday", tried everything "1", "2", "7" values the have no effect.

Comment: thank you @GunnarHjalmarsson for your time, every application :  the gnome-shell calendar applet, gnome-calendar and california has a different settings about "first_workday", so may be i will just forget it for a while, since the problem affects me only.

Comment: The "Regional Formats" option should work. If you want help to figure out why it doesn't for you, please ask a new question specifically about that.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, which is to add these lines to ~/.bashrc:
`LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, this is somewhat cleaner and more robust: it doesn't involve customising Ubuntu's locale files.

In Ubuntu, you can
assign locale components by editing the file **`/etc/default/locale`**.

> ```
> LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
> LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
> LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
> LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
> ```

Which means: I want software messages in American, but time, paper size and units in British i.e.weeks starting with Mondays, A4, metric.

So change it according to your region and requirements. Hope this solves your problem.

Found it on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=6798112#post6798112).

Comment: One problem with this suggestion (which I otherwise would prefer personally over generating my own locale): Does is exist a SUPPORTED locale with first_workday 1 (i.e. Sunday)?

Comment: doesn't work, the system is configured only with the language choosen as menues and windows language.

Answer (score 0):

After reading countless articles, I tried different methods to force the locales, I finally succeeded by editing ~/.bashrc and adding these lines :

```
export LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8 
export LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
export LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
export LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8
export LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
export LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
export LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
export LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
export LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
export LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
export LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

And of course there no such GUI application to achieve that.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)